# Creating multiple instances of a constructor with different values

Tags: java, constructor, multiple-instances

I have a class with a constructor

```java
public class Test {
  private static String name;

  public Test(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public static String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

Here I've created 2 instances of the constructor and used System.out.println() to output the "getName()" function from both instances in the terminal

```java
Test test = new Test("Tom");
Test test1 = new Test("Kenny");

System.out.println(test.getName());
System.out.println(test2.getName());
```

output:

```
Tom
Tom
```

Both of the outputs we're "Tom", how would I make it to where test.getName() outputs "Tom" and test2.getName() outputs "Kenny

I've looked for answers on StackOverFlow, google, etc and can't find anything so help would be very much appreciated

Comment: remove static keyword from your name field, and also from your getName function

Answer (score 1):

Your field is static, meaning that all objects you create for this class share the same value.

```
private static String name -> private String name
```

For non-static fields every object has it's own value.